# Teamcity buildpath change nativescript project name

Tags: teamcity, nativescript

Teamcity create a path BuildAgent/work/d455sdffs654... and change my nativescript project name and app name, i try make a new folder and change to this new folder but the project name not change.

```
npm install --save-dev nativescript-dev-webpack
tns platform remove android
tns platform add android 
tns build android --bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like your project name to be independent of its folder name, you may update the value for `CFBundleDisplayName` key in `App_Resources/iOS/info.plist` for iOS.

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>YourAppName</string>
```

For Android you may modify the value of `app_name` and `title_activity_kimera` keys in `App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`.